# logout from phpmyadmin when create new database

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, wamp64

i have strange problem to work with phpmyadmin in Wamp64

i login to phpmyadmin with "root" and no password easily , but when i click on any database or try to create new one suddenly it logout and the weird things is i cant login anymore with the root (no pass ) info

and i get  "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" message !

i try to disable antivirus , firewalls , using different Browsers and ...

but no success at all

If i Stop All Services and Enable it again i can login again but the problem still come and cant do anything in phpmyadmin

Comment: What version of WAMPServer and what version of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit
WampServer Version 3.0.0 64bit
apahche 2.4.17
mysql 5.7.9
php 5.6.16 , phpmyadmin 4.5.2  , i can work with my local wordpress sites , login to it and post and change settings , it`s weired that phpmyadmin is only problem

Comment: Suggest upgrade to WAMPServer v3.0.8

Comment: well the problem is wamp not recommend to upgrade and replace version and say for not lose database or problems use fresh install . but i cant even backup my current databases and other stuff with this problem

Comment: The `Wampserver 3.0.8 32/64 bit x86_x64 (Cumulative Update.)` only updates WAMPServers own code. It does not effect Apache/MYSQL/PHP. No new version of anything other than WAMPServers own code will change. Your databases will be safe

Comment: Then you can [view this page](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and download the newer phpMyAdmin4.7.0. These are addons and will just update the specific WAMPServer feature selected